# My Python Selenium Code doesn´t work at a linking text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
 <ol style="line-height: 1.7rem">
      <li>Connect a <a class="text-primary" id="newService">repository</a>.
       </li>
      <li>Create a <a class="text-primary" id="newProject">project</a>.
       </li>
</ol>
```

Code:

```
  driver.find_elements(By.ID,"newProject").click()
```

I try to run the python-selenium Code by clicking on a link, but i get the
following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0):

`.find_elements()` returns list of elements and **list** doesn't have `click()` method. Instead Use `find_element()` which will return **webElement**, which has `click()` method.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID,"newProject").click()
```

You can use `LINK_TEXT` as well

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"project").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The html you have provide is very less, but if there is a link then you can try two methods.

Method 1:

```
# The text mentioned on the clickable place
text = "new project"
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, text).click()
```

Method 2:

```
# Get the "href" attribute in that element

href_link = driver.find_elements(By.ID,"newProject").get_attribute("href")
driver.get(href_link)
```

Hope this helped